# How to disable scrolling of comboBox from keys arrow Up\Down when it closed?

Tags: c#, winforms

The arrow keys should scroll only pictureBox (placed in panel). It works fine.
But it also scroll through comboBox items though it is closed (droppedUp).
How to disable it?

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     comboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
     comboBox1.DroppedDown = false;
     comboBox1.Items.Add("111");
     comboBox1.Items.Add("222");
}
 
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == Keys.Down)
    {
          Point current = panel1.AutoScrollPosition;
          Point scrolled = new Point(current.X, -current.Y + 50);
          panel1.AutoScrollPosition = scrolled;
    }

    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

I had read about Control.PreviewKeyDown event:
[preview key event](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-RU/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.previewkeydown?view=windowsdesktop-5.0)
and also found another example:
[preview key event](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1121828/How-do-I-stop-auto-selection-with-down-arrow-key-i)
but I cannot understand how it used in my case.

Comment: Add `return true;` to ensure that the keystroke is not used anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Hans Passant commented, you must return true. Also, add some other keys that maybe change the selected item in the combobox:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == Keys.Down || 
        keyData == Keys.Up ||
        keyData == Keys.PageDown ||
        keyData == Keys.PageUp)
    {
        Point current = panel1.AutoScrollPosition;
        Point scrolled = new Point(current.X, -current.Y + 50);
        panel1.AutoScrollPosition = scrolled;
        return true;
    }

    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works!!! I had make in such way:    if (keyData == Keys.Down 
    {
        Point current = panel1.AutoScrollPosition;
        Point scrolled = new Point(current.X, -current.Y + 50);
        panel1.AutoScrollPosition = scrolled;
        return true;
    }  if (keyData == Keys.Up
    {
        Point current = panel1.AutoScrollPosition;
        Point scrolled = new Point(current.X, -current.Y - 50);
        panel1.AutoScrollPosition = scrolled;
        return true;
    }...  Thanks @Hans too!